# URI must be a string or UriInterface with Goutte Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4, goutte

I am getting the above error when i try to authenticate my proxy with  Goutte Plugin in Laravel .
Below is the code :

```
$client = new Client();
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption(['proxy' => 'http://x.x.x.x:80']);
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption(['auth' => ['username', 'pass', 'Basic']]);
$url  = 'http://ifconfig.me';
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$status  = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();
dd($status);
```

any suggestions please . Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

`$crawler = $client->request('GET', ['base_uri' => $url]);`